# Excel VLOOKUP(sum of two values, array(sum of value 1 + 2)

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

The title may be as vage as possible, but i'm new at this and i'm trying.

I want have a sheet with the setup:

```
User Role | Permission
```

But the a permission could also apply for multiple User roles,

So i want to create a more user friendly sheet
Where i plot:

```
              User role x | User role y| User role z
Permission 1
Permission 2
Permission x
```

And want to display this to true or false, or something.

But i am kind of stuck because my wildest VLOOKUP is just a lookup for 1 value in another sheet. i also saw some form of match and index combined, maybe that's something that could work?

Could you guys help me out with this?

To clarify. I want to set the value to true when in the sheet first there's a row with both the user role and the permission. When this is true, then it should be true. if there's a user role but not the permission, its false. Also the other way around. So only when there's a row in sheet 1 with column A{X} and B{X} combined equals {X}1 and A{X}

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? What are the conditions for showing True/False?

Comment: i added some text in the question itself. hope this clarifies things up

Comment: So can a user span multiple permissions?  Or is it like if a user has Permission x then they automatically have Permissions 1 and 2?

Comment: You can achieve it easily with pivot table, add first column to column labels, second column to row labels, any column to Value area. Set options to display 'False' in empty cells, and set Number format to `\T\r\u\e`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of any worksheet names or actual cell references makes this hard to provide a turn-key formula but perhaps you can transcribe this formula from the image for your own purposes.

[image: COUNTIFS Permissions]

The formula in B2 is,

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$7, B$1, $G$2:$G$7, $A2))
```

Fill both right and down as necessary. The `AND` function was added to accommodate your request for a TRUE/FALSE answer. If removed, you will get the numerical count of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

- Make sure the data in your first sheet is sorted first by user role, then by permission.
- Add a column to your first sheet that contains a unique hash of user role and permission. For example, if these are both numeric values, in columns A and B, and the maximum value of permission is less than 100, you could use:

  = A1 * 100 + B1
- Now, you can do a VLOOKUP against that hash column (let's call it C). So, in the second sheet, in B2, you'd put

  = NOT( ISNA( VLOOKUP(B$1 * 100 + $A2, Sheet1!$C:$C, 1, FALSE) ) )

This will return TRUE whenever the VLOOKUP can find a value on the hash column that corresponds to the hash of the column and row headers, and FALSE when it can't.